# How to resize/enlarge a PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java

I know the constructor of PriorityQueue in Java needs a size parameter. How to determine it beforehand? What if I need to enlarge the queue or resize it after some removal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to provide a size parameter, the default constructor will return one with a default initial capacity of 11. This capacity will be incremented by 2 x whenever it is needed, so you don't really need to worry about that.

The only purpose of providing a size in advance, is to save time so it doesn't have to grow too often, since that takes some time (although noting noticeable).

Comment: but when I need to supply a `Comparator` object, I need to provide a parater for size too, correct?

Comment: @littleEinstein Yes in that case you do since the constructor requires it, so just provide your best bet of the capacity you will need, does not really matter too much.

Answer (score 4):

The size you are speaking about is `initialCapacity`. You do not have to enlarge the queue: it will grow automatically when it is needed.

Comment: what if I want it to be trimmed down so that i can save some space in the case that my queue is no longer changing?

Comment: @littleEinstein Then you have to create a new PriorityQueue and discard the old one, `theQueue = new PriorityQueue(theQueue);`

Answer (score 3):

PriorityQueue is unbounded, it can grow as big as your memory allows, and it will grow automatically when needed. The `initialCapacity` parameter is just a hint to reserve room for that many elements initially.

Read more in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Answer (score 2):

Collections are managed for you after the construction. What you do with this constructor is giving java a hint (to allocate enough memory for the array).

I think java's priority queues are based on the array-based heap (should and may be checked in jdk if interested)